# running pip to install python packages from inside powershell on vista

Tags: windows, powershell, installation, virtualenv, pip

im trying to follow this pretty good guide
http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/28/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/

but im getting the following error when trying to install virtualenv

```
PS C:\> pip install virtualenv
The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file
, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was include
d, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ pip <<<<  install virtualenv
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFound
    Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

im a mac user normally, so i understand how to use pip, not sure why this isn't working though. not very good with powershell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, emailed the author of the article and he pointed out that c:\Python27\Scripts needs to be on the path / PS $env:Path for pip to be picked up.

Once thats sorted, it'll install fine.